# Rupay card number is not detecting in one of the rn - credit- card library of react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-credit-card

Using above Library I created payment card system in my app, visa & master cards are working fine but Rupay card number is not validating correctly. Problem is Rupay card & Discover card, both cards start with digit 6. It might be the problem, I just need Rupay card has to detect in this Library.
[image]

Above image from Wikipedia payment card number page. You can find the Rupay card & Discover card numbers start with same digit.

Should I go the Library node modules & change things ? How can validate rupay card number ??? Please help

Answer (score 0):

RuPay card BIN number also start with 3, 5, 6 & 8

Contact RuPay card customer support on twitter handle @RuPay_npci

RuPay card tieup with Discover & JCB card for International payment.

RuPay-Discover variant co-badged cards start with 6,
RuPay-JCB variant co-badged cards start with 3,

Domestic RuPay card variant cards start with 5, 6 & 8.

Contact RuPay card support on twitter or directly contact through NPCI website.